# SSO MVC ASP.NET CORE 1.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, asp.net-core-mvc

Can someone explain to me how to achieve single-sign on? I have an MVC ASP.NET core web app(let's say www.internalsite.com), how can the app get the user credentials automatically and authenticate etc.? I need a very clear explanation on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

By using www.internalsite.com I guess you are talking about a site on an intranet, right? How are you hosted? IIS in front of Kestrel? If so, then it's quite straightforward, you just need to configure IIS to foward the Windows identity (coming from a Kerberos token usually) by setting the proper value in the web.config: `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` as explained here: [Asp.net Core Web API - Current user & Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161234/asp-net-core-web-api-current-user-windows-authentication/42163175#42163175) and make sure you have a controller/action protected by an `[Authorize]` tag so that the IIS middleware is challenged and set the identity of the request as explained here: [NTLM authentication on specific route in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581132/ntlm-authentication-on-specific-route-in-asp-net-core/42582188#42582188) No much code to write in your project. If you are using another hosting setup, WebListener, it is pretty much the same.

Another solution, would be to do SSO by client certificate which has the advantage of working cross domain, but SSO by Kerberos is by far easier and usually doing a good job on an intranet.