# .Net 6: Enable Windows and Anonymous authentication for one

Tags: authentication, .net-6.0

I work on a .Net core application and I need to mix windows and anonymous authentication within the same endpoint(s). So the goal is to be able to determine the windows user but the endpoint should also work when no windows user is present (aka windows authentication fails).

My problem is that when I use the Authorize attribe (as shown in the example below), the endpoint will only be called when windows authentication succeded. If I additionaly add the [AllowAnonymous] attribute, the User is never authenticated.

Example: (

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    _log.LogDebug("IsAuthenticated = " + this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString());
    _log.LogDebug("Authenticated Name: " + this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.Name);

    return View();
}
```

How can this be done in .Net 6.0? It should be really simple as authentication and authorization should be separated but it seems they are quite intertwined. I haven't found a solution after extensive googling, checking the .net core source code and trying out myself.
Is there a good way to solve this?

Remark 1: there are solutions for .Net core 3.1 but then don't work in .Net 6 [Enable both Windows authentication and Anonymous authentication in an ASP.NET Core app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778600/enable-both-windows-authentication-and-anonymous-authentication-in-an-asp-net-co)

Remark 2: we have endpoint that have to work with Windows Authentication only and other with anonyomous authentication. These both work fine within the same application. It is really about being able to detect the windows user in an endpoint that otherwise supports anymous authentication.

Comment: I have to correct myself. The solution posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778600/enable-both-windows-authentication-and-anonymous-authentication-in-an-asp-net-co works for .Net 6 as well (import namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication to access the extension method) but it doesn't work when windows auth is disabled in IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (or better we) have found a solution that works even when Windows authentication is disabled on IIS.  It is not very elegant but this is what we came up with. The idea is basically to trigger another call to an endpoint to determine if the user is actually a windows loging or not. If this call is successful, then we know we have a windows user and can act accordingly, for example do a redirect to an endpoint that requires windows authentication.

Remark: If you can control the IIS settings - which probably is often the case - , then I suggest you go with the solution proposed here:
[enable-both-windows-authentication-and-anonymous-authentication-in-an-asp-net-co](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778600/enable-both-windows-authentication-and-anonymous-authentication-in-an-asp-net-co) )

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestWindowsAuthAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        });

        var response = await client.GetAsync($"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Request.Host}{HttpContext.Request.PathBase}{HttpContext.Request.Path}/HasUserWindowsAuth");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Yes, now we know that user indeed has windows authentication and we can act upon it
            return RedirectToAction("QuickLogin", input);
        }

        // No windows credentials have been passed at this point
        return View();
    }


    [HttpGet("HasUserWindowsAuth")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public IActionResult HasUserWindowsAuth() => Ok();


    [HttpGet("QuickLogin")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> QuickLoginAsync(LoginModel input, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var user = this.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault(i => i System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity && i.IsAuthenticatd);
        // do something with that user
    }
```